# How can i call a variable used in UIKit file to a SwiftUI file

Tags: swift, function, variables, swiftui, uikit

i call a UIKit  view of phonenumberview  in my swiftui project   by UIViewControllerRepresentable it work but now i need to call the variable used in the UIKit file to my swiftui file
this is the function of uikit :

```
 func phoneNumberView(didChangeText nationalNumber: String, country: JNCountry, forPhoneNumberView phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) {
        self.phoneNumberLabel.text = "\(self.phoneNumberView.getDialCode() + nationalNumber)"
self.phoneNumberView.setViewConfiguration(self.getConfigration())
    }
```

and my goal is to use the self.phoneNumberLabel.text in my swiftui file i don't know how to call it
this is the code of the uikit file :

```
import UIKit
import JNPhoneNumberView

class JNPhoneNumberViewExample: UIViewController {
    
    /// Phone number view
    @IBOutlet  weak var phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView!
    
    /// Phone number label
    @IBOutlet  weak var phoneNumberLabel: UILabel!
    
    /**
     View did load
     */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        
        // Set delegate
        self.phoneNumberView.delegate = self
        self.phoneNumberView.setDefaultCountryCode("TN")
        self.phoneNumberView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.phoneNumberView.setViewConfiguration(self.getConfigration())
        self.phoneNumberView.setPhoneNumber("")
        self.phoneNumberView.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
        self.phoneNumberView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.phoneNumberView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.phoneNumberView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
    
}

extension JNPhoneNumberViewExample: JNPhoneNumberViewDelegate {
    
    /**
     Get presenter view controller
     - Parameter phoneNumberView: Phone number view
     - Returns: presenter view controller
     */
    func phoneNumberView(getPresenterViewControllerFor phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }
    
    /**
     Get country code picker attributes
     - Parameter phoneNumberView: Phone number view
     */
    func phoneNumberView(getCountryPickerAttributesFor phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) -> JNCountryPickerConfiguration {
        let configuration = JNCountryPickerConfiguration()
        configuration.pickerLanguage = .en
        configuration.tableCellInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
        configuration.viewBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
        configuration.tableCellBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
        
        return configuration
    }
    
    /**
     Did change text
     - Parameter nationalNumber: National phone number
     - Parameter country: Number country info
     - Parameter phoneNumberView: Phone number view
     */
    func phoneNumberView(didChangeText nationalNumber: String, country: JNCountry, forPhoneNumberView phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) {
        self.phoneNumberLabel.text = "\(self.phoneNumberView.getDialCode() + nationalNumber)"
    
        self.phoneNumberView.setViewConfiguration(self.getConfigration())
    }
    
    /**
     Did end editing
     - Parameter nationalNumber: National phone number
     - Parameter country: Number country info
     - Parameter isValidPhoneNumber:  Is valid phone number flag as bool
     - Parameter phoneNumberView: Phone number view
     */
    func phoneNumberView(didEndEditing nationalNumber: String, country: JNCountry, isValidPhoneNumber: Bool, forPhoneNumberView phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) {
        let validationMessage = isValidPhoneNumber ? "Valid Phone Number" : "Invalid Phone Number"
        self.phoneNumberLabel.text = (validationMessage)
        self.phoneNumberLabel.textColor = isValidPhoneNumber ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.red
    }
    
    /**
     Country Did Changed
     - Parameter country: New Selected Country
     - Parameter isValidPhoneNumber: Is valid phone number flag as bool
     - Parameter phoneNumberView: Phone number view
     */
    func phoneNumberView(countryDidChanged country: JNCountry, isValidPhoneNumber: Bool, forPhoneNumberView phoneNumberView: JNPhoneNumberView) {
        let validationMessage = isValidPhoneNumber ? "Valid Phone Number" : "Invalid Phone Number"
      // self.phoneNumberLabel.text = "International Phone Number: \n \(self.phoneNumberView.getPhoneNumber()) \n \(validationMessage)"
        
        self.phoneNumberLabel.textColor = isValidPhoneNumber ? UIColor.blue : UIColor.red
    }
   
    private func getConfigration() -> JNPhoneNumberViewConfiguration {
        let configrartion = JNPhoneNumberViewConfiguration()
        configrartion.phoneNumberTitleColor = UIColor.black
        configrartion.countryDialCodeTitleColor = UIColor.black
        configrartion.phoneNumberTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        configrartion.countryDialCodeTitleFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        configrartion.phoneNumberAttributedPlaceHolder = NSAttributedString(string: "00 000 000")
        return configrartion
    }
}
```

and in the swiftui file i put a varible to receive the phonenumberlabel data comes from uikit file

Comment: Use binding. This will revert back you the `phoneNumberLabel.text`.. Plz elaborate your code.

Comment: done i edited my question  , my goal is when the user enters his number i can do the verification of this number by swiftui that's why i need to get the variable used in the uikit file